# Jasmine Unit Test for Function outside Class not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I was trying to test a static function within a logo-manager.component.ts file but the function is outside of "export class LogoManager"

```
export class LogoManagerComponent implements OnInit {
...
}

function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) {
...
}
```

I tried to do an import in logo-manager.component.spec.ts like

`import * as LogoManagerObj from './logo-manager.component';`

then

```
const fileObject = getFakeEventData({name: 'name', type: 'image/png', size: 500});
spyOn(LogoManagerObj, 'dataURLtoFile').and.returnValue(fileObject);
```

but I get the error Argument of type '"dataURLtoFile"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"LogoManagerComponent"'.

Besides trying with spyOn, I tried with spyOnProperty but didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

`dataURLtoFile` does not exist in `LogoManagerObj`.

Try the following:

```
export class LogoManagerComponent implements OnInit {
...
}

export function dataURLtoFile(dataurl, filename) { // add export here 
// so we can have a handle on it in the tests
...
}
```

```
import * as LogoManagerObj from './logo-manager.component';

.....

const fileObject = getFakeEventData({name: 'name', type: 'image/png', size: 500});
spyOn(LogoManagerObj, 'dataURLtoFile').and.returnValue(fileObject);
// to get a handle on the component, it would be LogoManagerObj.LogoManagerComponent
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. This approach is working very well.